StreamlitAPIException: st.session_state.user_question cannot be modified after the widget with key user_question is instantiated
I wanted to clear the input feild whenever a question is submitted but got this error:
StreamlitAPIException: st.session_state.user_question cannot be modified after the widget with key user_question is instantiated

.....
def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="ChatBot")
    st.header("ChatBot")

    # Use a form for user input
    with st.form(key='user_input_form'):
        user_question = st.text_input("Ask a Question", key="temp_user_question")
        submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')

        if submit_button and st.session_state["temp_user_question"]:
            user_input(st.session_state["temp_user_question"])
            st.session_state["temp_user_question"] = '' # Clear the input field after submission

Another approach:
def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="ChatBot")
    st.header("ChatBot")

    # Use a form for user input
    with st.form(key='user_input_form'):
        user_question = st.text_input("Ask a Question", key="temp_user_question")
        submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')

        if submit_button and st.session_state["temp_user_question"]:
            user_input(st.session_state["temp_user_question"])
            st.session_state["temp_user_question"] = None # Clear the input field after submission

